# Trying to append a text input to a variable

Tags: javascript, php, d3.js, pie-chart

I am using HTML, JavaScript, a JavaScript library called d3.js and PHP to create a program that will ask the user to enter a set of numbers. Once the user submits the set of numbers a pie chart is generated. Each time the numbers are changed a new pie chart is generated.

The problem that I am having is I am using a text input to take in the numbers, they are separated by a comma, but I want to append my text input to my data variable ( variable for my pie chart) so that each time a set of numbers are inserted a new pie chart will appear. How am I able to do this?

This is my text input:

```
< input type="text" name="first" min="1" max="100" >
```

This is my original data variable for my pie chart but I want to append my input to my data variable:

```
var data [4,5,11,,2,10,7];
```

How do I append my text input to my data variable ( variable for my pie chart) so that each time a set of numbers are inserted a new pie chart will appear?

Comment: what is the question ?

Comment: question is unclear

Comment: the question is " How do I append my text input to my data variable ( variable for my pie chart) so that each time a set of numbers are inserted a new pie chart will appear?"

Answer (score 0):

Use this code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-US">
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <input type="text" name="first" min="1" max="100">
    <input type="submit" name="btnSubmit" id="btnSubmit">
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var data = new Array();
        $('#btnSubmit').click(function() {
            var value = parseInt($("input[name=first]").val(), 10);
            if(!isNaN(value)){
                data.push(value);
                console.log(data);
            }
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Result I got with 4 times click button

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```js
var data = [4,5,11,2,10,7]

$("#submit").click(function(){
    var input = $("#myInput").val().split(",")
    $("#myInput").val("")

    input.forEach(function(item){
        data.push(parseInt(item, 10))
    })
    
    // data now includes new input.  Pass to your chart building function here
   alert(data)
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id ="myInput" type="text" name="first" min="1" max="100">
<button id="submit">
  submit
</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use input.split(','),which will convert comma separated values to array. Then use concat function to combine array.

Comment: I don't understand